# I can't send mails with PHPMailer in Openshift

Tags: php, openshift, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to send email in my PHP app. I think is problem of Openshift or something I have to configure cause I've tried on localhost and it worked. I use Gmail as email host.
When I tried on Openshift I had no errors, just a blank page but in Openshift log I see this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'librerias/class.smtp.php' (include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/lib/openshift/545b8e30e0b8cd0983000153/app-root/runtime/repo/librerias/PHPMailer.php on line 1004, referer: http://ciclismo-ciclismoermua.rhcloud.com/registro.php

Comment: use `git add . -A -f`, commit, push and check again.

Comment: @PeeHaa: how do you edit posts like these? what IDE you use?

Comment: @PeeHaa won't tell you this, because secret ... but Visual Studio ... definitely ...

Comment: The error looks pretty obvious to me.  Does librerias/class.smtp.php  exist?  If so, is it in the include path?  If not, then should it be or should you modify the code to use the full path?

Comment: @itachi What do you mean?

Comment: @PeeHaa How did you edit this post? using what IDE or tool?

Comment: @JoeWatkins let's see it comes out or not.... ;)

Comment: @Devon librerias/class.smtp.php exists, of course. I don't touch anything of PHPMailer library because it works fine on localhost. The 1004 line is like this:  require_once $this->PluginDir . 'class.smtp.php';

Comment: For all of you wondering I use [butterflies](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/real_programmers.png)

Comment: Maybe your web server doesn't have read permissions in the location where the files are?

Comment: @Synchro I have no idea. How can I know what permissions has the web server?

Comment: Something like `sudo su - www-data ls -al /path/to/your/files`, depending on your OS.

Comment: @Synchro thanks man, that totally fixed.

Comment: So are things fixed then? If so go ahead and submit the answer below so others can see the resolution.